# Why do I get a wrong answer in this C code?

Tags: c, pointers

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun(int a,int b,int c){
    int *ret;
    ret = &a -1;
    (*ret)+=8;
}
int main(){
    int x;
    x = 0;
    fun(1,2,3);
    x = 1;
    printf("x is %d\n",x );
    return 0;
}
```

I believe x should be 1, but it's actually 0. What causes this?

Comment: `ret = &a -1;` -- well, now you have undefined behavior.

Comment: This is undefined behavior.  Function `fun` is writing to the stack at an address that is offset from one of its arguments.  At that point your runtime environment has been corrupted.  Segmentation faults are a likely outcome of this sort of thing.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I am getting the output as expected as 1 for the value of x. 
Check it here https://ideone.com/H9GfS8

Comment: @ShubhamAgrawal -- undefined behavior means that anything can happen, including output of the expected result. `ret = &a - 1` causes undefined behavior, and so the entire program is invalid. For purposes of pointer arithmetic, a pointer to an `int` behaves as a pointer to the first element of an array of one `int`. Given `int arr[1];`, it is undefined behavior to even form the address `&arr[0] - 1`, but OK to form `&arr[0]`, and `&arr[0] + 1` (but you can't dereference the last one). So in OP code, `&a - 1` causes undefined behavior.

Comment: @ShubhamAgrawal -- [here is a link to the C11 Standard discussion of this](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6)

Comment: Thank you ,I understand that the abnormal access to the pointer causes a write failure in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking some very undefined behavior. The variable `a` in the function is at an address (*probably* on the stack) that is normally only accessible to the function. Decrementing that address results in an undefined location. You don't know what's there at all, so you have no idea what incrementing it by 8 will do.